# Trouble with Importing modules

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I have this code in my Index.js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var check = require('../nodemailer/check.js');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/checkemail', function(req, res, next) {
var email = 'email';
console.log(email);
check.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) { 
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error); 
    } 
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
module.exports.email= email;
//console.log(module.exports.email);
  });
 res.render('checkemail', { title: 'check' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

And this in my check.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var rter = require('../routes/index.js');
//var dho = rter.email;
console.log(rter.email)
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
    host: 'server206.web-hosting.com', 
    port: 26, 
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: { 
        user: 'noreply@swiftcircle.website', // generated ethereal 
        pass:  'Miracle1994' // generated ethereal password } }); 
    }
});

var mailOptions = { 
    from: 'noreply@swiftcircle.website', 
    to: rter, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line 
    //text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body 

    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
 };
```

I exported the variable 'email' successfully from index but it shows undefined in check.js when i tried to import...

In the code, i exported the variable email then, required it in the check.js with the '.property' and tried to console.log it but it returned 'undefined' what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: You've created a circular dependency: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in the intertwined `require` of modules.
The `index.js` module requires the `check.js` module in line 4; The `check.js` module then requires the `index.js` module in line 2.

This prevents the `check.js` module to access exported variables in the `index.js` module.

You should probably think on how to refactor the code so that the `email` property you'd like to access is accessible in some other way (for example, by use of an utility module, that gets the `email` property set and read at the appropriate time).

Comment: Another issue is that i have to refer to the check.js file to get the transporter object. how do i get around with it?

Comment: Pardon me if I misunderstand, but the `email` property is used in the `mailOptions` object, that is used before setting the `email ` property.  
In case this is correct, then the simplest thing might be to create an external file, `email-utility.js`, with a 'static' property `email` (together with a setter and a getter).
This utility file can then be required in both index.js and check.js: in index.js you'd call the setter, and in check.js you'd call the getter (better yet: the mailOptions should be a function, so that you'd get the current value of the `email`).
I hope this might help!

Comment: Sorry but please could u give me a example with a test script?

Answer (score 0):

I got it right now! This is how i did it...

```
exports.mail = function mail(x){
    //my codes in my check.js
}
```

Then, i imported it in my index.js like this...

```
var check = require('../nodemailer/check.js);
check.mail(email);
```

It worked!